# Probability of digits in a number being in ascending order

Tags: probability

Given a set of 4 distinct numbers that can be chosen from [0-9], what is the probability that after selecting, the four digit number thus formed will have all digits in ascending order.

Comment: Is 0 allowed as the first digit?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 3):

For any choice of $4$ digits, there is only $1$ arrangement such that the $4$ digit number will be in ascending order out of $24$ numbers.

So the probability is $\frac{1}{24}.$

Answer (score 0):

Only the non zero digits can be a part of the answer as we are required to form a $4$ digit number while also maintaining the digits in ascending order, which is not possible when $0$ is included.

Now, the number of possible arrangements in such a case are :  $\binom{9}{4}=126$
Also there is only one way of arranging these digits in increasing order 
$\implies$ no of favourable outcomes $= 126\cdot1!=126$

the total number of ways of forming a $4$ digit number from the digits is : 
$\binom{10}{4} = 1260$
We have two cases:
1. $0$ is selected, then we have $18$ ways of arranging the $4$ digits.
2. $0$ is not selected, then we have $24$ ways of arranging the $4$ digits.
$\implies$ total no of possible outcomes $= 1260\cdot(18+24) = 1260\cdot42 = 52920$

Hence $P(4\text{ digit number with digits in increasing order}) = \frac{126}{52920} = \frac1{420}$

I have considered the without repitition case

Comment: I do not know the LaTeX commands for writing combinations.

Comment: I will help with your $\LaTeX$, but you should look at Ofir's answer.